# Illegal String Offset and Validation not working in PHP

Tags: php

I'm making a validation system for my website. Well actually, my code works if I didn't put any parameter in my `$_POST`(like`$_POST['Login']`). If I put any *parameter* in my `$_POST`, it returns an error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset: 'username' in C:\ ...

My *sample* authentication form:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="Password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="remember">
      <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="on"/> Remember Me
    </label>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" name="Login"/>
</form>
```

The script that will be processed if the form was submitted:

```
<?php
    require_once 'init.php';
    $user = new User();
    if($user->isLoggedIn()){
      Redirect::to('index.php');
    }
    $validate = new Validate();
    if(Input::exists()) {
        if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
            $validation = $validate->check($_POST["Login"], array(
                'username' => array('required' => true),
                'password' => array('required' => true)
            ));
        }
    }
?>
```

The *validation* class:

```
<?php
    class Validate {

        # Set the variables
        private $_passed = false,
                $_errors = array(),
                $_db = null;

        # Construct or establish connection to the database
        public function __construct(){
            $this->_db = Database::getInstance();
        }

        # The validation/checking code or the main brain of the code
        public function check($source, $items = array()){
            # Run a ` for each ` for each item in the fields
            foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
                # Run a ` for each ` for every rule in the items
                foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {
                    # Set the variables of `value` and `item`
                    $value = $source[$item];
                    $item = sanitize($item);

                    if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                        $this->addError("{$item} is required");
                    } else if (!empty($value)) {
                        switch($rule) {
                            # Case: Minimum
                            case 'min':
                                if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                                    $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                                }
                                break;

                            # Case Maximum
                            case 'max':
                                if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                                    $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                                }
                                break;

                            # Case: Match
                            case 'matches':
                                if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                                    $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}.");
                                }
                                break;

                            # Case: Unique
                            case 'unique':
                                $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));

                                if($check->count()) {
                                    $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                                }
                                break;
                            # Case: Not match
                            case 'notmatch':
                              if($value === $source[$rule_value]) {
                                $this->addError("{$rule_value} must not match {$item}.");
                              }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(empty($this->_errors)) {
                $this->_passed = true;
            }
        }

        # ~ ADD ~ and error
        public function addError($error) {
            $this->_errors[] = $error;
        }

        # ~ RETURN ~ the errors
        public function errors() {
            return $this->_errors;
        }

        # ~ CHECK ~ if it is passed
        public function passed() {
            return $this->_passed;
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is a file, and rule number in the error. Can you tell me whitch rule it is (not the rule number)?

Comment: Here is the picture (link) of the following error: [link](http://imgur.com/a/S5aoA)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling $validate->check and passing it $_POST["Login"] as first argument but based on your HTML you should be passing only $_POST. When you pass $_POST["Login"] then the form inputs should have attribute name as name="Login[username]" .

Right now when you pass $_POST["Login"] its actually an empty array so that could be the reason why you are getting Illegal string offset

Comment: I tried to `die(var_dump($_POST['Login;]));` and it displays: value: Login, which is the value of the input button to submit the form? Any chance of fixing this?